# Highlight firefox taskbar icon when notification comes in on KDE plasma

Tags: firefox, notifications, taskbar, kde-plasma, wayland

On Plasma desktop, I use a Firefox  instance to chat on mattermost (I does not want to use the electron-based app due to several reasons). However, even allowing notifications on firefox, when new message comes in there is only system notification (and sound), staying about 5s. The icon is not highlighted, as many chat apps do. If I'm not sitting at my desktop at the moment when new message arrives, I'll miss it because the system notification is gone and no highlights on taskbar icon.

So, possible when new notification comes, is it possible that Firefox taskbar icon stays light up until I switch to it?

Highlight here means the orange color in default plasma theme, like the right-most icon in this figure:
[highlighted app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KpHRl.png)

I tried googling on two directions:

1. Let Firefox light up itself. I searched Firefox configs about how to highlight taskbar app, because other chat apps can highlight their icons, so there must be an protocol on handling taskbar icon.
2. Let the system light up the Firefox icon once it has a notification. I observed that when I click an url, Firefox icon is highlighted, and it goes normal when I switch to Firefox (the switch is not automatic, since I use Wayland). Similar things happens on dolphin, if I open a new location from command-line. So focus switching may cause taskbar icon to be highlighted. But I can't found any effective method to configure this behavior. I cannot find a way to change the highlight color, either (maybe try a different theme can change the color but I prefer to stick with the default one)